# Android hide soft keyboard IME

Tags: java, android

Below is a bit of code that I managed to get to work to hide the soft keyboard on android. It works by the user clicking anywhere on the screen (outside of a `EditText` input/s) to hide the IME soft keyboard. It registers a `OnTouchListener` to the `ScrollView (id="@+id/sv_background)` which when the screen is touched it hides the IME soft keyboard via the `InputMethodManager` code. I have set the scroll view as the parent layout in this case but it also works with any other layout view.

I hope this is useful to someone out there in Android land.

XML

```
<ScrollView 
android:id="@+id/sv_background" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <other views and EditTexts/>

</ScrollView>
```

Java

```
private ScrollView svBackground;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newentry);

    svBackground = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.sv_background);
    svBackground.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(svBackground.getWindowToken(), 0);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is this like a post instead of a question?

Comment: Eclipse didn't automatically suggest this so I'll just say it, you need to import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager; for this to work. Thanks for it! Saved me a little bit of time solving it myself.